# get_activate not found in gtk::Swtich

Tags: user-interface, rust, gtk, glade

I've been following a project based book which uses `gtk` and `glade` to build a UI. Went all fine until I got to using a `gtk::Switch` which the book uses like this:

```
let builder = gtk::Builder::from_string(include_str!("glade_config.glade"));
// ...
let is_dead_switch: gtk::Switch = builder
    .get_object("is_dead_switch")
    .unwrap();
```

Later on, to get the switch state it uses `is_dead_switch.get_activate()` but the method seems to no longer be a thing. I've looked into the documentation and found that `gtk::Switch` only has `gtk::Switch::new` listed as method. Anyone knows what's missing or what's wrong?

Cargo.toml dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
gio = "0.9.1"

[dependencies.gtk]
version = "0.9.2"
features = ["v3_22"]
```

`glade` config file stating this part:

```
<child>
    <object class="GtkSwitch" id="is_dead_switch">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
    </object>
    <packing>
       <property name="expand">False</property>
       <property name="fill">True</property>
       <property name="position">1</property>
    </packing>
 </child>
```

Comment: looks like it was moved to the [`SwitchExt`](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/trait.SwitchExt.html) trait?

Comment: I had similar problems where Visual Studio Code wanted me to import some *Ext. In those cases, I forgot to `use gtk::prelude::*;` as this imports most of the needed traits and therefore enables functions beside of `new` that you may want to call on a gtk struct.